# How to draw hypercube graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to draw hypercube projections like those on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Graphs):
[image: 6-cube graph]

I tried with

```
HypercubeGraph[6]
```

but the graph does not look right; it is not symmetric, it is rotated by some degrees and some vertices that should be merged together (represented on the above figure with different colors) are not. Then I found the [Wolfram MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubeGraph.html) that suggests [`GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphData.html) might be helpful.

```
GraphData[{"Hypercube", 6}, "EdgeRules"];
Graph[%]
```

Produces a similar graph as [`HypercubeGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HypercubeGraph.html) but now it is more symmetric.

```
GraphData[{"Hypercube", 6}, "EdgeList"];
Graph[%]
```

Produces a different graph, even more symmetric but the vertices are obviously still not merged:

[image: Mathematica graph]

Since I'd like to draw several different hypercube graphs manually merging the vertices is not an option. What's the easiest way to draw symmetric hypercube graphs in Mathematica with some vertices merged like in the example from Wikipedia?

Comment: There isn't even the same number of vertices in the outer ring.., I'm afraid that _Mathematica_ can't do better than that.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you need the vertices merged?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the way `GraphData` works has changed in the last five years, but the code suggested by [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubeGraph.html), `GraphData[{"Hypercube", n}]`, seems to work:

```
GraphicsRow@Table[GraphData[{"Hypercube", n}], {n, 6}]
```

[image]

With colors:

```
gg = GraphData[{"Hypercube", 6}];
vc = PropertyValue[gg, VertexCoordinates];
colors = {1 -> Red, 2 -> Orange, 4 -> Yellow, _Integer -> Automatic};
dupes = vc /. Counts@vc;
HighlightGraph[gg, MapIndexed[Reverse@*Style, dupes /. colors]]
```

[image]

(The option `VertexSize` fails to work on the graph `gg`. Maybe it's a bug.)